# White screen shows up during regular use after El Capitan upgrade

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan

MacBook Pro retina (2013). Yosemite was doing fine; but after I upgraded it to El Capitan, I get white screen showing up every few minutes during regular coding and browsing. I searched online but most white screen problems of Mac users happened during the upgrade, but mine is during regular use. Anyone knows how to debug problems like this?

EDIT: some more clues --- 1. the pointer is still visible and I can move it around as well; 2. I can even take a screenshot of the white screen; 3. when I swipe up on touchpad I still get to "show my desktop", but after I swipe down the white screen comes back.

Comment: Looks off topic question. But not closing soon for 15 year service with Linux. Hope your problem resolves.

Comment: What happens when you do a triple-finger swipe to left then to right?

Comment: I use Mac platforms for coding (mainly java and eclipse, but lately using node and webstorm) and never had this kind of issues. I believe it can be a kind of malware or some compatibility issue with any specific program you are using.
I think it will be hard for someone give you an specific answer about this problem, as it seems to be related to your specific configuration.

Comment: By the way, it can be some malware installed in your computer. My wife once installed a thing called Clean my Mac and that stupid program messed her MacBook and I needed to make a clean install to get rid of that crap

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is a scheduled job that starts up in the background and runs an incompatible app. What does your console say when you reboot?

You need to remove 3rd party internet related software that isn't fully compatible with El Capitan and then reboot.

Also, did you try the fixes recommended 
[here](http://www.i4u.com/2015/10/95937/how-fix-os-x-10111-white-screen).

Specifically
1) enter single user mode and run `/sbin/fsck -fy`
2) boot into safe mode

You may also need to remove these items (tuntap, a VPN software):
/Library/StartupItems/tap
/Library/StartupItems/tun